# Child container failed in JAX_RS and jersey web service

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jax-rs

It is simple web service using JAX_RS and Jersey. But there is an error `A child container failed during start`. 
This the error log.

```
A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/RestfulWebServiceServer]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/RestfulWebServiceServer]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
```

`pom.xml`

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core -->
 <dependencies>
 <dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
<version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/asm/asm -->
 <dependency>
<groupId>asm</groupId>
<artifactId>asm</artifactId>
<version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server -->
  <dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
<version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-servlet -->
 <dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
<version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
<version>1.19</version>
 </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
   </plugins>
  </build>
  </project>
```

`User.java`

```
package entities;



  public class User{

private String name;
private String id;
private String address;
private String email;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public User(String name, String id, String address, String email) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.address = address;
    this.email = email;
}
public User() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


 }
```

`UserJSONService.java`

```
package ws;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import entities.User;

@Path("/json/user")
public class UserJSONService {

@GET
@Path("/get")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public User getUser(){
    User u1 = new User();
    u1.setName("John Doe");
    u1.setId("1");
    u1.setAddress("Kolkata");
    u1.setEmail("someone@gmail.com");


    return u1;
}

@POST
@Path("/post")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response sendUserInJSON(User user) {

    String result = "User saved : " + user;
    return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();

}

public static double JAVA_VERSION = getVersion ();

static double getVersion () {
    String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
    int pos = version.indexOf('.');
    pos = version.indexOf('.', pos+1);
    return Double.parseDouble (version.substring (0, pos));
}

 }
```

`web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name>RestfulWebServiceServer</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-    class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>ws</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

using the correct dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/asm/asm -->
<dependency>
<groupId>asm</groupId>
<artifactId>asm</artifactId>
<version>3.3.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

instead of asm 3.1 solved my issue.